# Is there anything like a dime?

Tags: single-word-request, regional, colloquial

In the U.S. there is the well established formal label *"[dime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dime_%28United_States_coin%29)"* for a 10 cent coin. Now that the currency in Germany is also denoted in cents I am wondering if we had anything similar for this 10 cent coin:

[image]

Is there any widely accepted and understood maybe colloquial term other than [Zehncentstück](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zehncentstueck)? Are there regional differences either in Germany or in Switzerland, Austria, and other German speaking regions outside of Germany?

Comment: There is no such word I know of. The Euro coins and bills are in use for ten years now but I've never heard of any coin or bill called with such a term.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sechsling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding [this article](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_8/r8_f2a/) there are several words in use to name the 10-Cent coin.
The article point out, that the word *Groschen* is still in use after changing from D-Mark to Euro. Another often used word seems to be *Zehner*.

[image]

This article based on a survey (its the answer to question 2a of whatever; I tried to find the appropriate question, but failed), but I do not believe the full correctness of this article. The map on top of the page shows me, that West Germany use commonly *Zehner* and *Groschen*, but I can't remember when I heard it last (*Groschen*) and *Zehner* is in my understanding *10 Euro*.

Comment: I also think that's wrong. I never heard someone calling 10 cents a "Groschen" or "Zehner" and I live and work in different parts of germany. Besides, if someone would ask for a "Zehner", I would guess he means 10 €, not cents.

Comment: In Swabia there is a clear distinction between *"Zehnerle"* and *"Zehner"* - may be that's why people use it there.

Comment: @TimBüthe: I live in Baden-Württemberg and "Zehner" is quite common here. "Zehnerle", too.

Comment: This map is absolutely wrong. I have never heard anyone in Austria say anything like what the map says. _Groschen_ was heavily used in Austria. After all it was part of the official currency. We had _Schilling_ and _Groschen_.

Comment: I've already heard Groschen for 10cent, and *Heiermann* for 2€ (previously used for 5DM). Let alone that many people here say "Euronen" rather than "Euro" or "Euros" ;)

Comment: I haven't heard Groschen since my grandfather died 20 years ago. It's no longer in use, and probably a lot of younger germans won't understand it nowadays.

Answer (score 9):

> Now that the currency in Germany is also denoted in cents ...

Funny enough it's the other way around. *Before* we had cents in Germany there was the name "[Groschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Groschen)" for the Zehnpfennigstück. This also produced nice words like "[Groschengrab](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Groschengrab)" which was used for gambling machines and parking meters. I haven't heard that word for a while.

Since we use cents in Germany I have never heard of a special name for the 10-cent-coin. Looks like neither "Groschen" nor "dime" was adopted for it.

Comment: Yes, the old Deutsche Mark coins and bills had names. I can remember the term "Heiermann" for the 5 Mark coin.

Comment: I didn't know this name, so thanks for telling me @Tichodroma. Always nice to spend some time on Wikipedia: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiermann

Comment: You could use "Groschen" though, it's quite likely to be understood. At least by people aged 25+, I guess. It might even evoke a smile :-)

Comment: @Tichodroma: nice comment, your're right with "Heiermann". There was also "Zwickel" for the 2 Mark coin (no WP entry to link to :-( ) - i'm not sure whethere "Zwickel" is still in use for the 2 Euro coin.

Comment: @tohuwawohu [It is mentioned on wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwickel), but haven't an own site. It is also used for 2 Euro, following the short advice on WP.

Comment: Actually, I wonder where the name "Groschen" comes from. In Polish, the "Grosz" is simply the main subdivision of the Polish currency, the "Złote" (100 Groszy = 1 Złote). I remember how little sense it made for me, that Germans said "Groschen" for the 10 Pfennig coin, while I was used to the 1 Grosz coin.

Comment: @polemon latin *denarius grossus* (german: *dicker Denar* [Denar = Roman currency]). Since  13 century used for silver coin with great worth. But then copied to other coins. Since it isn't any offical currency in *german empire* it was still used for a tenth of 1 D-Mark

Answer (score 4):

In Austria, I have heard dimmiutives for the Cent coins: *Einserl*, *Zweierl*, *Fünferl*, *Zehnerl*, *Zwanzgerl*, *Fufzgerl*. This use is consistent with the pre-Euro usage, where the same dimmiutives would be used for the respective Groschen values (i.e. a 1995 *Zehnerl* would be 10 Groschen ~ 1.3 Cent).

I do know that the Germans used "Groschen" for the 10 Pfenning coin, but I have not heard this appropriated to the 10 or 5 Cent coin. And even if, Austrians wouldn't use this, having a former currency where the Groschen was a real subdivision.

As for Switzerland: I do suspect that they don't have too much need for a Cent-label, having a different currency anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I know of is "Zehner", the same goes for the 20ct ("Zwanziger") and 50ct ("Fünfziger"). The only problem is, that the same works for 10€, 20€ and 50€, so the real meaning comes from the context.

Comment: maybe in some situations but around here they are usually used for 10€, 20€ and 50€

Comment: As Flo suggested, it can depend on context if "Zehner" means 10¢ or 10€. If you are asked for some small change it would be clear that "Zehner" means 10¢.
Also, for 20€, 50€ we say sometimes "Zwanni", "Fuffi".

Answer (score 1):

As @nd01 already mentioned, we do have a different currency (swiss franc).
The corresponding counterpart to the cents in Germany would be Rappen in Switzerland.

For the 10 Rappen coin we use the following Terms:

> zehner
>
> zehnerli
>
> zehnräppler

For the other coins worth less than one franc (5,10,20 and 50 Rappen), the terms are analogue to the above mentioned.

The only coin that really has a Name is the 5 Franc coin, which is called

> Fünfliber